# pyinstaller pyqt5 configparser.nosectionerror:no section "png_path": failed to execute script .py

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting

> ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'TestInformation'

using this code:

```
def LoadTestInformation(self): 
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser() 
    print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'App.cfg'))
```

[image: error]

Comment: The posted code does not match the error message.

Comment: the configparser.py:dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

print(dir_path)

config_path = os.path.join(dir_path,'imgconfig.conf')
print(config_path)
conf = configparser.ConfigParser()


conf.read(filenames=config_path,encoding='utf-8')

qt_png_path = os.path.dirname(dir_path)+'\\'+conf.get('png_path','qt_png')
pics_path = os.path.dirname(dir_path)+'\\'+conf.get('png_path','pics')                                     the conf:[png_path]
qt_png = images\qt_png\
pics = images\qt_png\pics\
after pyinstaller ,i get the errors

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link under your post to add your code. [Format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) as code blocks.